# Setting tableViewCell's title based on whats typed in a textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Right now, I have tableViewController with a button to add more. When the button is tapped a new cell appears with the title "New Habit". When the cell is tapped, a DetailViewController appears with a textfield. When the textfield is tapped, a UIPicker is shown with three options. First is "Posture", second is "Palaudies Abbs", and The third option is custom, which when custom is selected the keyboard is replaced for a keyboard. With the keyboard you type in a custom habit, and it is displayed in the textfield. When Posture or palaudies is selected, the tableViewCell is named to the selection (which you can see how in the code). Now the problem is setting the custom option to the title of the cell. Currently I have been able to take the string and I tried to set it to the deleage like the others are, but it ends up setting the title to nothing.

Here is my code

## DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol DetailViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)setCellName2:(NSString *)cellName;
@end

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate> {
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <DetailViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIToolbar *toolBar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *backButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPickerView *Picker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *barDoneButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *customHabit;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *cellNames;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *habitField;
- (IBAction)backToRoot:(id)sender;
@end
```

## .m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

#import "HabitViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *pickerData;

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize  Picker, toolBar, backButton, barDoneButton, flexSpace, cellNames;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.pickerData = @[@"Posture",@"Paludies Abbs",@"Custom"];

    toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [toolBar sizeToFit];

    [toolBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red_navigation_bar.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:nil];
    // Done button on toolbar
    barDoneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                  target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(releasePicker)];
    // Back button on toolbar

    backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                 target:self
                                                 action:@selector(backToPicker)];

    // Habit PickerView

    Picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    Picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    Picker.delegate = self;
    barDoneButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];

    // Toolbar above picker

    [toolBar setItems:@[flexSpace, barDoneButton] animated:YES];

    self.habitField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

    [self.habitField addTarget:self action:@selector(customHabitChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];

    [self.habitField setInputView:Picker];

    cellNames = @"New Habit";

}
- (void)customHabitChanged {
    self.customHabit = self.habitField.text;
    cellNames = self.customHabit;
}
- (void)backToPicker {
    [toolBar setItems:@[flexSpace, barDoneButton] animated:YES];
    [self.habitField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.habitField setInputView:Picker];
    [self.habitField becomeFirstResponder];
}
- (void)releasePicker {
    [self.habitField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.habitField setInputView:Picker];
    [toolBar setItems:@[flexSpace, barDoneButton] animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)backToRoot:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return self.pickerData.count;
}


-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return self.pickerData[row];
}


-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    cellNames = [[NSString alloc] init];
    int select = row;
    if (select == 0) {
        cellNames = @"Posture";

        [self.delegate setCellName2:cellNames];

    }
    if (select == 1) {

        self.habitField.text = @"Palaudies Abbs";

        cellNames = @"Palaudies Abbs";


    }
    if (select == 2) {

        cellNames = @"Custom";

        [self.habitField resignFirstResponder];
        [self.habitField setInputView:nil];
        [self.habitField becomeFirstResponder];
        [toolBar setItems:@[backButton, flexSpace, barDoneButton] animated:YES];
        self.habitField.text = nil;
        self.habitField.placeholder = @"Custom";
        [self.delegate setCellName2:cellNames];

    }
}

@end
```

---

## HabitViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface HabitViewController : UITableViewController <DetailViewDelegate> {
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selectedCell;

@end
```

## .m

```
#import "HabitViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface HabitViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *myCells;
}
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *cellName2;


@end

@implementation HabitViewController

@synthesize selectedCell;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    [self.editButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.33 green:.33 blue:.33 alpha:1]];

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    addButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.33 green:.33 blue:.33 alpha:1];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];



}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!myCells) {
        myCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [myCells insertObject:@"New Habit" atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

#pragma mark - Table View



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return myCells.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = myCells[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [myCells removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    }
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    DetailViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.delegate = self;
}
#pragma mark - DetailViewDelegate

-(void)setCellName2:(NSString *)cellName {
    NSInteger selectedRow = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row;
    NSLog(@"%@", cellName);
    [myCells replaceObjectAtIndex:selectedRow withObject:cellName];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm fairly confused. I don't see how this can work with the "Palaudies" text, nor how the `setCellName2:` method could work without tapping the add button first. Is there something more to your code that you've left out?

Comment: It's in there, that's all the code I have. After the picker option is selected, it sends it what is selected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the delegate is being invoked when the text editing begins rather than when it ends.  There won't be anything valuable in the cellName parameter until the editing is finished.

In the custom case, you must make the textField the first responder and then react when the user is finished editing.

To catch that event, have the DetailVC be the text field's delegate, and respond to `textFieldDidEndEditing`.  In that method, call your delegate with the textField.text.

Comment: Can you explain how I can do this?

Comment: I set it as its delegate, and ad far as i can see the code is already set to when it finishes editing, what else?